# How to pass data from MSBuild to XAML build workflow

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a MSBuild script that has data I need to use in my TFS 2013 XAML build definition.  Is there a way to transfer data from MSBuild into the XAML build workflow?

I originally was thinking I could get access to the MSBuild properties in my XAML, but this appears to be a one-way path i.e. XAML -> MSBuild via the parameters to the RunMSBuild activity but not the other way around.

Comment: Just saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769175/pass-value-from-msbuild-task-to-tfs-build-workflow which appears to be a duplicate, but the solution isn't very elegant.  Perhaps this isn't supported?

Comment: Do you mean you want to customize the build process template? What function do you want to achieve?

Comment: You may check blog "Properly incorporate MsBuild arguments into your build process template" to see whether this is helpful: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/07/properly-incorporate-msbuild-arguments.html

Comment: Yes, I understand how to pass arguments into a XAML workflow build from the build definition, but that's not my problem.  I want to pass arguments from MSBuild,  run via the RunMSBuild activity within XAML workflow, to a variable in the workflow.  My first thought was that I should be able to read properties that were set in MSBuild and put those into a workflow variable.  However, I don't see a way to make that happen.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I have customized the build template, and need to get a version number that is being generated in my MSBuild script into the build workflow.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this is write the version number into a file via [WriteLinesToFile Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164305.aspx) and then add a custom activity in XAML workflow to read this number.

Comment: This is the same solution that I pointed out in my first comment to the question.  If that's the only way to accomplish it,  then we should delete this question as a duplicate.